# best way to convert the this html file into an xml file using python

Tags: python, html, xml

this html is [here](https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=2&ik=a0b1e46c9c&view=att&th=1296be43b8e3bbd9&attid=0.1&disp=inline&zw) :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"><html><head><META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head><body>

    <div bgcolor="#48486c">

        <table width="720" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" background="http://title.jpg" height="130">

            <tr height="129">

                <td width="719" height="129"></td>

                <td width="1" height="129"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr height="1">

                <td width="720" height="1"></td>

                <td width="1" height="1"></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

        <table width="720" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" height="203">

            <tr height="20">

                <td width="719" height="20"></td>

                <td width="1" height="20"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr height="69">

                <td width="719" height="69" valign="top" align="left">

                    <table width="719" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">

                        <tr>

                            <td bgcolor="a5fdf8" width="390"><b>Stream Name</b></td>

                            <td bgcolor="a5fdf8" width="61"><b>Status</b></td>

                            <td bgcolor="a5fdf8" width="61"><b>Duration</b></td>

                            <td bgcolor="a5fdf8" width="185"><b>Start</b></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="390">c:\streams\ours\Sony_AVCHD_<WBR>Test_Discs_60Hz_00001.m2ts</td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#D0D0D0">----</font></td>

                            <td width="61">00:00:02</td>

                            <td width="185">2010/06/15-15:06:17</td>

                        </tr>

                    </table>

                </td>

                <td width="1" height="69"></td>

            </tr>

            <tr height="113">

                <td width="720" height="113" colspan="2" valign="top" align="left">

                    <table width="721" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">

                        <tr bgcolor="a5fdf8">

                            <td width="299"><b>Test Category</b></td>

                            <td width="61"><b>Error</b></td>

                            <td width="62"><b>Warning</b></td>

                            <td width="275"><b>Details</b></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#099eac">All Tests (Sony_AVCHD_Test_Discs_60Hz_<WBR>00001.m2ts)</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#ff0000">34787</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#800000">  ETSI TR-101-290 Tests</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#800000">  ISO/IEC Transport Stream Tests</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#800000">  System Data T-STD Tests</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#099eac">  Prog(1)</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#ff0000">34787</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#099eac">    VES(0xe0)</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#ff0000">34787</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#1010F0">      H.264/AVC Conformance</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#ff0000">34718</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275">

                                <a><font color="#ff0000">Sony_AVCHD_Test_Discs_60Hz_<WBR>00001.m2ts_Prog(1)_PID(0x1011)<WBR>_H264_Conf.txt</font></a><br>

                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#101010">        Sequence</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#101010">        Picture</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#101010">        Slice</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#101010">        Macroblock</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#ff0000">34718</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#101010">        Block</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#1010F0">      HRD Tests</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#ff0000">69</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275">

                                <a><font color="#ff0000">Sony_AVCHD_Test_Discs_60Hz_<WBR>00001.m2ts_Prog(1)_PID(0x1011)<WBR>_H264_HRD.txt</font></a><br>

                            </td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#101010">        HRD level</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#ff0000">69</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#800000">      Video T-STD Tests</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#099eac">    AES(0xfd)</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#000000">0</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#808080">      Audio Level Tests</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#808080">Disabled</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#808080">Disabled</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                        <tr bgcolor="white">

                            <td width="299"><font color="#800000">      Audio T-STD Tests</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="61"><font color="#800000">No Lic</font></td>

                            <td width="275"></td>

                        </tr>

                    </table>

                </td>

            </tr>

            <tr height="1">

                <td width="719" height="1"></td>

                <td width="1" height="1"></td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div>



</body></html>
```

has any python lib to do this ?

thanks

Comment: What kind of XML file do you want? This file is already just a schema file away from being perfectly valid XML.

Comment: er, plus or minus an unclosed tag here and there :-)

Comment: It already is valid XML, just close the META tag.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) gets you almost all the way there:

```
>>> import BeautifulSoup
>>> f = open('a.html')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(f)
>>> f.close()
>>> g = open('a.xml', 'w')
>>> print >> g, soup.prettify()
>>> g.close()
```

This closes all tags properly.  The only issue remaining is that the `doctype` remains `HTML` -- to change that into the doctype of your choice, you only need to change the first line, which is not hard, e.g., instead of printing the prettified text directly,

```
>>> lines = soup.prettify().splitlines()
>>> lines[0] = ('<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"'
                '"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">')
>>> print >> g, '\n'.join(lines)
```

Answer (score 12):

lxml works well:

```
from lxml import html, etree

doc = html.fromstring(open('a.html').read())
out = open('a.xhtml', 'wb')
out.write(etree.tostring(doc))
```

Comment: it has many file , and i can't find the etree method from lxml

Comment: lxml.etree is a module, lxml.etree.tostring is a function.  Maybe you have an installation problem?

Comment: This solution works perfect when someone is dealing with autogenerated html pages (e.g. java doc in android for parsing methods and variables). BeautifulSoup's soup.prettify() will add unwanted spaces. This solution won't add extra spaces when you don't want them to be there.

Answer (score 0):

To piggyback off @Alex Martelli, as of `Python 2.5`, there is an xml module that comes baked into the standard library:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/xml.html

You could strip all HTML tags off, then format into xml and use the baked in XML library instead of bringing in another dependency. This is only advisable if you trust the source of the XML as you would be susceptible to all the standard XML vulnerabilities.