# How to remove whitespace in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a bunch of HTML I'm parsing with BeautifulSoup and it's been going pretty well except for one minor snag. I want to save the output into a single-lined string, with the following as my current output:

```
    <li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">
                    Zazzafooky but one two three!
                </span></li>
<li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">
                    Zazzafooky2
                </span></li>
<li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">
                    Zazzafooky3
                </span></li>
```

Ideally I'd like

```
<li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">Zazzafooky but one two three!</span></li><li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">Zazzafooky2</span></li>
```

There's a lot of redundant whitespace that I'd like to get rid of but it's not necessarily removable using `strip()`, nor can I blatantly remove all the spaces because I need to retain the text. How can I do it? It seems like a common enough problem that regex would be overkill, but is that the only way?

I don't have any `<pre>` tags so I can be a little more forceful there.

Thanks once again!

Comment: How are you printing your output?

Comment: You can do what browsers do: Collapse all adjacent whitespace (in text) into single spaces.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is how you can do it without regular expressions:

```
>>> html = """    <li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">
...                     Zazzafooky but one two three!
...                 </span></li>
... <li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">
...                     Zazzafooky2
...                 </span></li>
... <li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">
...                     Zazzafooky3
...                 </span></li>
... """
>>> html = "".join(line.strip() for line in html.split("\n"))
>>> html
'<li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">Zazzafooky but one two three!</span></li><li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">Zazzafooky2</span></li><li><span class="plaincharacterwrap break">Zazzafooky3</span></li>'
```

Answer (score 19):

Old question, I know, but beautifulsoup4 has this helper called [stripped_strings](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#strings-and-stripped-strings).

Try this:

```
description_el = about.find('p', { "class": "description" })
descriptions = list(description_el.stripped_strings)
description = "\n\n".join(descriptions) if descriptions else ""
```

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub(r'[\ \n]{2,}', '', yourstring)
```

Regex `[\ \n]{2}` matches newlines and spaces (has to be escaped) when there's more than two or more of them. The more thorough implementation is this:

```
re.sub('\ {2,}', '', yourstring)
re.sub('\n*', '', yourstring)
```

I would think the first would only replace multiple newlines, but it seems (at least for me) to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

In case you came here after getting troubled by BeautifulSoup prettify().  I think this solution won't add extra spaces.

```
from lxml import html, etree

doc = html.fromstring(open('inputfile.html').read())
out = open('out.html', 'wb')
out.write(etree.tostring(doc))
```

Please see this [Ian Bicking's answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3115596/8127390)

Parsing via xml.etree is simple...

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('out.html')
title = tree.find(".//title").text
print(title)
```