# How to handle an empty HTML element without the ending slash?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, parsing, html-parsing

I try to convert an HTML page into a tree structure. I have derived this class (I removed what I actually do with each tag as it's not relevant) :

```
class PageParser(html.parser.HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("start "+tag)
    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print("end "+tag)
    def handle_startendtag(self, tag, attrs):
        print("startend "+tag)
```

I expected empty elements to trigger the `handle_startendtag` method. The problem is that, when encountering an empty element like `<meta>`, only the `handle_starttag` method is called. The tag is never closed from my class' point of view :

```
parser = PageParser()
parser.feed('<div> <meta charset="utf-8"> </div>')
```

prints :

```
start div
start meta
end div
```

I need to know when each element has been closed to correctly create the tree. How can I know if a tag is an empty element ?

Comment: From the docs:
_"This parser does not check that end tags match start tags or call the end-tag handler for elements which are closed implicitly by closing an outer element."_ https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html

Comment: You should either be inputting strict XML where the `<meta>` tag is no longer valid and you have to write it as `<meta/>` or keep track of a list of tags that might come as empty tags, like the `<br/>` or the `<meta/>` tags.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115448/best-way-to-convert-the-this-html-file-into-an-xml-file-using-python

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), and specifically this example:

> Parsing an element with a few attributes and a title:
>
> ```
> >>>parser.feed('<img src="python-logo.png" alt="The Python logo">')
> Start tag: img
>     attr: ('src', 'python-logo.png')
>     attr: ('alt', 'The Python logo')
> ```

We can determine that this is the expected behavior.

The best suggestion come from @HenryHeath 's comment: Use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

If you don't want to use it though, you can work around the expected behavior of `HTMLParser` as follows:

- This is a list of every [HTML 5.2 void element](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#void-elements).
- Create a list with those element names:

  ```
  void_elements = ['area', 'base', ... , 'wbr']
  ```
- In `handle_starttag` check if the tag is in the `void_elements` list:

  ```
  class PageParser(html.parser.HTMLParser):
      def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
          if tag in void_elements:
              # DO what should happen inside handle_startendtag()
              print("void element "+tag)
          else:
              print("start "+tag)
  ```

Good luck :)

Comment: Your solution worked, thank you. Parsing a Twitter page, I found that they use the `link` tag as an empty element, but it's not in the list you linked to. I don't know if it should (maybe it's not standard), but I put it there in case someone encounters the same problem.